# Upper Bound for Scapegoat tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Pat Morin's free textbook: Open Data Structures: Scapegoat trees.
http://opendatastructures.org/ods-cpp.pdf
Page 174-175

Scapegoat trees track n=number of nodes and q=upper bound.

What is this upper bound? I thought it was the maximum number of nodes that could be in the tree depending on it's height. It is not. How do I find the Upper bound so that I can make this tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context, `q` is what [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scapegoat_tree) calls `MaxNodeCount`:

> [..] MaxNodeCount simply represents the highest achieved NodeCount. It is set to NodeCount whenever the entire tree is rebalanced, and after insertion is set to max(MaxNodeCount, NodeCount).

(where `NodeCount` is `n` in the book)

Also, if after deletion

```
NodeCount <= α * MaxNodeCount
```

then the whole tree is rebalanced, and MaxNodeCount is reset to the value of NodeCount. In the book, the value of α is 0.5.

Comment: So If I have a tree of height =3. The max node count would be 2 to the third power -1. Because that is the maximum amount of nodes I could stuff in the tree? This is why the example in the book (8.1) is n=q=10 even though q should be much larger that n, every re balance sets q=n so they won't always be visually correct.

Comment: @user2899211 MaxNodeCount isn't the theoretical maximum, i.e., 2^n-1, but the maximum number of nodes this tree had since it was rebalanced for the last time. The rebalancing operation resets MaxNodeCount, and insertion may or may not increase it.